# I want to use user.posts, property I defined in redux/reducers/user.js, but I keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to make an instagram feed that shows up the posts from people whom I follow. However, my screen doesn't show any post even though the person whom I follow have total five posts. Following is what I did.

`dispatch({type:USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts, uid})`
This code returned the following:

```
//a part of code from users.js
case USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersLoaded: state.usersLoaded+1,
                users: state.users.map(user => user.uid ===action.uid ?
                    {...user, posts: action.posts} : user)
            }
```

I believe posts are now saved inside the object user.

```
//a part of code from user.js
const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: [],
    following: [],
}
```

In my Feed.js file, I put `posts=[...posts, ...user.posts]` code to combine two arrays. There's an error popped up saying that
'ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object

This error is located at:
in Feed (created by Connect(Feed))'

I found out that user has 'user:{"dateOfBirth":20000626,"email":"Tester2@naver.com","sex":"female","name":"Kimmy","uid":"w2y8RD9eHGa5Kr4NP0fKuoUj3VA3"}' values. It doesn't contain posts[].
According to user.js, it must have posts[] array. What did I do wrong??

```
useEffect(()=> {
    let posts = [];
    console.log("props.usersLoaded:"+props.usersLoaded);
    console.log("props.following.length: "+ props.following.length);
    if(props.usersLoaded==props.following.length){
      for(let i=0;i<props.following.length; i++){
        const user = props.users.find(el=>el.uid ===props.following[i]);
        console.log("user:"+user);
        if(user != undefined){
          //posts=posts.concat(user.posts); 
          //if I use the upper code instead of the one underneath it, it doesn't throw an error but items in the array 'user.posts' were not added to the array 'posts'. 
          posts=[...posts, ...user.posts]
          //the original is making an error probably because user.posts is not defined
        }
      }
      posts.sort(function(x,y){
        return x.creation - y.creation;
      })
      setPosts(posts);
    }
    console.log("Feed posts:"+ posts);
  }, [props.usersLoaded])
```

I tried to define posts in another way.
`posts=posts.concat(user.posts);`
This change made the code do not make any error but it seemed like the array 'posts' did not include user.posts.

```
//Feed.js file
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList, Button} from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' 
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

function Feed(props){
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    let posts = [];
    console.log("props.usersLoaded:"+props.usersLoaded);
    console.log("props.following.length: "+ props.following.length);
    if(props.usersLoaded==props.following.length){
      for(let i=0;i<props.following.length; i++){
        const user = props.users.find(el=>el.uid ===props.following[i]);
        console.log("user:"+user);
        if(user != undefined){
          //posts=posts.concat(user.posts);
          posts=[...posts, ...user.posts]
          //the original is making an error probably because user.posts is not defined
        }
      }
      posts.sort(function(x,y){
        return x.creation - y.creation;
      })
      setPosts(posts);
    }
    console.log("Feed posts:"+ posts);
  }, [props.usersLoaded])
  
//anytime following list is updated, we want this function to re-render

  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={1}
            horizontal={false}
            data={posts}
            renderItem={({item})=>(
            <View style={styles.containerImage}>
              {item && item.user && (
                <Text style={styles.container}>{item.user.name}</Text>
              )}
              {item && (
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.downloadURL}}/>
              )}
            </View>
          )}/>
        </View>
      </View>

    )
  
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  containerInfo:{
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  containerGallery:{
    flex:1,
  },
  containerImage:{
    flex:1/3,
  },
  image:{
    flex:1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
})

const mapStateToProps = (store) =>({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  following: store.userState.following,
  users: store.usersState.users,
  usersLoaded: store.usersState.usersLoaded,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Feed);
```

```
//this is an index.js file. redux/actions/index.js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import {USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE} from '../constants/index'

export function fetchUser(){
    return((dispatch)=> {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                if(snapshot.exists){
                    dispatch({type:USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data()})
                }
                else{
                    console.log('does not exist')
                }
                
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUserPosts(){
    return((dispatch)=> {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("UserPosts")
            .orderBy("creation","asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc=> {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return{id, ...data}
                })
                
                dispatch({type:USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts})
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUserFollowing(){
    return((dispatch)=> {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("following")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userFollowing")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{ //snapshot is triggered whenever following user is added or deleted
                let following = snapshot.docs.map(doc=> {
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return id;
                })
                
                dispatch({type:USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE, following})
                for(let i=0; i<following.length; i++){
                    dispatch(fetchUsersData(following[i]));
                }
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUsersData(uid){
    return((dispatch, getState) => {
        const found = getState().usersState.users.some(el=>el.uid ===uid);
        console.log('fetchUsersData triggered1');
        console.log("found:"+found);
        console.log("users:"+getState().usersState.users);
        console.log(getState().usersState.users);
        if(!found){//user doesn't exist in the data array
            console.log('fetchUsersData triggered2');
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection("users")
                .doc(uid)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot)=>{
                    if(snapshot.exists){
                        console.log('fetchUsersData triggered3');
                        let user = snapshot.data();
                        user.uid=snapshot.id;
                        dispatch({type:USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, user});
                        dispatch(fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid));
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('does not exist')
                    }
                    
                })

        }
    })
}

export function fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid){
    return((dispatch, getState)=> {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(uid)
            .collection("UserPosts")
            .orderBy("creation","asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                console.log('fetchUsersFollowingPosts triggered')
                try{
                const uid = snapshot.ref && snapshot.ref.parent && snapshot.ref.parent.id;
                //const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1]; //how to get uid of user
                console.log("{snapshot, uid}: "+{snapshot, uid});
                const user = getState().usersState.users.find(el=>el.uid ===uid); //find: user object를 return

                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc=> {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return{id, ...data, user}
                })
                console.log("fetchUsersFollowingPosts posts:"+posts)
                dispatch({type:USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts, uid})
                console.log("getState(): "+getState())}
                catch(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
                
        })
    })
}
```

```
//users.js file. redux/reducers/users.js
import { USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE} from "../constants/index"

const initialState = {
    users: [],
    usersLoaded: 0,
}

export const users  = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [...state.users,  action.user]
            }
        case USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersLoaded: state.usersLoaded+1,
                users: state.users.map(user => user.uid ===action.uid?
                    //user이 있을경우 이게 trigger되야함.
                    {...user, posts: action.posts} : user)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
//user.js file. redux/reducers/user.js
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE} from "../constants/index"

const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: [],
    following: [],
}

export const user  = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.currentUser
            }
        case USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }
        case USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                following: action.following
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```